# Add module to django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiZwP.png)

**I have a problem when importing a personal module to the django administration panel**

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from facturas.models import Factura
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Factura)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import UUIDField, IntegerField, CharField, EmailField, DateTimeField
from django.utils import timezone


class Factura(models.Model):
    # id_asi = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True) #campo interno para consulta en la base de datos 
    ambiente = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    tipoEmision = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    razonSocial = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    nombreComercial = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

.serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from facturas.models import Factura

#agregado de campos necesarios para una factura 
class FacturaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Factura
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I am in the admin panel of django i can only add the module but not modify

Comment: do you want to customize the way it looks on the admin page ?

Comment: what do you mean by you can add the module but not modify, your question is unclear

Comment: Yes, I can resolved because I hadn't to put all the fields in serializers instead of fields='__all__'